# Inheritance and relationship on base abstract class with MVC, EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inheritance, relationship

i have this sample project:

Models:

```
public class Country
{
 public int ID{get; set;}
 public string CountryName{get; set;}
}

public abstract class Subject
{
  public int CountryID{get; set;}
}

public class Person : Subject
{
 public string PersonName{get; set;}
}

public class Company : Subjet
{
 public string CompanyName{get; set;}
}
```

Context:

```
public class SampleContext : DbContext
{
 public DbSet<Contry> Countries{get; set;}
 public DbSet<Person> Persons{get; set;}
 public DbSet<Company> Companies{get; set;}

 modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Map(m => { m.MapInheritedProperties();ToTable("Person"); });
 modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Map(m => { m.MapInheritedProperties();ToTable("Company"); });
}
```

And I get this error.

Error 3013: Problem in Mapping Fragment starting at line xxx: Missing table mapping: Foreign key constraint Subject_Country from table Subject(CountryID)

But, Subject is abstract and I dont wont such table in DB. When I use on Subject class only parameters like int or string, all is ok. But when I want use there some relationship, I get this error.

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: public DbSet<Contry> Countries{get; set;}  should be public DbSet<Country> Countries{get; set;}

Answer (score 0):

In your SampleContext the name of the 'Country' is misspelled.

```
public DbSet<Contry> Countries{get; set;}
```

Should be:

```
public DbSet<Country> Countries{get; set;}
```